# How to use Parameterized fixtures in pytest-bdd

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, bdd, pytest-bdd

I am trying to use parameterized fixture in my pytest-bdd framework.
Normal fixture works fine. But If I am passing parameters, it gives below error
`The requested fixture has no parameter defined for test:`

Below is my code(Sample). Waht is the correct usage here?

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[1,2])
def ba_data(request):
    print("this is fixture")
    return request.param


@given(parsers.cfparse('Collect testdata'))
def required_data(ba_data):
    print(ba_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to use parameterized fixture in pytest-bdd
you have to declare the scenario using `@scenario("yourfeaturename.feature","your scenario name")`

it would not work if you use the scenarios function as

```
scenarios("yourfeaturename.feature")
```

you will have to pass the fixture to the function below @scenario

```
@scenario("yourfeaturename.feature","your scenario name")
def test_mytest(ba_data):    
   pass


@pytest.fixture(params=[1,2])
def ba_data(request):
   print("this is fixture")
   return request.param


@given(parsers.cfparse('Collect testdata'))
def required_data(ba_data):
   print(ba_data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked !
But is there a way to avoid hard coding scenari name? in this case.

Answer (score 1):

it also does not work for fixture generated by pytest_generate_tests defined inside conftest.py

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
   if "numberinput" in metafunc.fixturenames:
      metafunc.parametrize("numberinput", [1, 2, 3])
```

guess pytest-bdd did not support fixture properly

Comment: Exactly, I tested it , metafunc does not work for pytest-bdd for now

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat hacky solution: use a global variable in your step definition file to create an object that you pass between tests.  Globals are generally bad but here they work fine.

For example:

```
    Scenario: Smoke test
    Given language English
    And terms:
        lines
        and
```

With the step definitions:

```
_lang = None

@scenario('../features/rendering.feature', 'Smoke test')
def test_smoke_test():
    pass

@given(parsers.parse('language {langname}'))
def given_lang(langname):
    global _lang
    _lang = langname

@given(parsers.parse('terms:\n{content}'))
def given_terms(content):
    print('terms for ' + _lang)
```

Running this gives the following:

```
sample_steps.py terms for English
```

If the step def file is only dealing with a certain set of tests, then globals could be kept to a minimum.

Note I'm a newcomer to pytest-bdd so there may be a better way to handle this, but after reading the docs and various posts, this is the best I could come up with.

Cheers!